# Find specific strings All Position from large string

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

I want to find all position of 'LIID' string into 'DATASTRING' column using which help to find all LLID values.

DATASTRING Column contains MIXED data its not valid XML file.

Query :

```
     select id , DATASTRING from mixdatatable
```

Output :

```
        id          DATASTRING

        1           ABC XYZ IS 1 ..
                    <ObjectValue /><CP /><SIProps ST="4" PL="False" PLS="" />
                    <STI_SummaryActiveProblemsField LIID="cdbd7044-ccde-11db-8cba-df0a56d89593" IID="37742a5f-7998-4715-8d43-0d7a19284d44" IR="True" RW="1">
                    <HD Title="Active Problems" /><ObjectValue />
                    <CP><PosReplace /><NegReplace /></CP><SIProps ST="4" PL="False" PLS="" />
                    -<STI_DxItem IID="d85c91e7-703f-4f8c-9a38-961fb2d14828" RW="1" LIID="03e4da86-d57c-408e-9479-b6fb97cc9a60"><HD Title=" unspecified "/>
                    <STI_US><ObjectValue><TextValue><![CDATA[
                    ]]></TextValue></ObjectValue><CP />
                    <LIID='71194038-8ffb-488b-8af5-5f1f1a679115'>
                    <SIProps ST="1" SS=" " PL="False" PLS="" />
                    </STI_US> AAAAAA
                    979816816/881783683618317381-817
```

I want to find all LIID values. LLID values lenth are '36' eg.'cdbd7044-ccde-11db-8cba-df0a56d89593'

Expected Output :

```
                      ID   LLID
                      1    cdbd7044-ccde-11db-8cba-df0a56d89593      
                      1    03e4da86-d57c-408e-9479-b6fb97cc9a60       
                      1    71194038-8ffb-488b-8af5-5f1f1a679115
```

PostgreSQL version 8.3

Note : i dont have acess to create function or procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, unnest(regexp_matches(datastring,'LIID=[''"]([0-9a-f-]+)','g'))
  from mixdatatable
```

Test on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c6653/2)

Comment: Thnks Thnks Thanks . i dont have word. Can you explain this .

Comment: @rohitpatil Unfortunately my English is bad :( What is not clear in this query ? Function `regexp_matches` (get array of substrings from sting) or regular expression

Comment: "LIID=[''"]([0-9a-f-]+)','g'"    what is tihs ?  @mike

Comment: @rohitpatil Regular expression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression  search LIID=, next `['"]` one of symbol (quotes), next `(...)` ("marked subexpression") `[0-9a-f-]` number OR char a,b,c,d,e,f OR `-`, `+` - repeat one or more times. regexp_matches return "marked subexpression" (contents of the parentheses). parameter `'g'` - global - serach all substrings. https://regex101.com/r/G7q21P/1

Comment: thnks bro.  can you tell mi for string "aaaa <LinkID>cc8855b0-d2eb-4eef-b958-ce8bc672542a</LinkID>" to fetch linkid ? . this is also placed in same DATASTRING column.this linkid presnt on same data.

Comment: @rohitpatil `<LinkID>([0-9a-f-]+)`

Comment: Thnks lot. frnd any time you can also ask me any help.  one more bro. same column have  " <![CDATA[ICD#B27.0]]>" i need to sort out only B27.0. if possible then Tell me